# Can I develop iOS app in os mavericks?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, operating-system, osx-mavericks

and can I install xcode? I want to make iOS app without using OS X . because I don't have imac and macbook!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an Apple Mac computer that can run OSX Mavericks to run Xcode. To distribute to the app store or test on device you need a paid $99/year Apple Developer Account. If you have a modern Mavericks-capable mac, you're fine.

If you are running on a PC, and wish to develop your app in JS/HTML/CSS, there are some options for you without buying a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand your question.

but you need OSX to program an iOS app, because without it you cannot install Xcode.

you can install Xcode on an OSX other than Mavericks, you can also try building a hackintosh, but thats a very bad idea.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You cant, every iOS native app has to be signed and processed with XCode before launching in App Store, so even if you find a way to code for iOS on PC or other OS (I dont really know how) you`ll necessarily need a Mac for processing and compiling the app in XCode for sending your project to iTunes Connect and publishing it in App Store.

I know is not the answer you hope, anyway Hope it helps.

PS: Draw up better your question because in the title you ask something different than in your content.

Answer (score 0):

To install Xcode you will need Mac OSx environment. You should have at least Mac-Mini or any other Mac(iMac/Macbook) to install and build a project and then submit to store(for submitting you will need a paid apple id, then you need to create certificate for distribution and then submit it to store.) If you are un able to use mac at the moment then you can install Mac os in your PC or laptop by using VMWare(you can only use for development, i guess for submission you will need Mac).

```
GoodLuck hope this helps you..
```